# Is it possible to have an unlimited precision floating point data type, in either visual basic, java, or c++?

Tags: java, c++, types

I am looking for a float based number (this number will have a fractional part) and will be ridiculously large in size(number of digits) Is there a way to have a data type variable that is bound in size only by the storage space available on your pc?

Comment: Something like [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for Java?

Comment: so you want a float decimal that is bound by the storage space and not the data type itself? My question would be why you need this? Precision is only good up to a point and after that it is pointless (pun intended)...

Comment: Yes, but if you want suggestions on what library/tool to use we do not do that here.

Comment: @NathanOliver: well, I am sure there is an exception when the main library supports it?

Comment: Google "arbitrary precision arithmetic"

Comment: @mszymborski If they want something in the "standard" that does it that is fine.  If they just want anything then that is not.

Comment: I believe the limitation is on the database/table, not the interface.  Java, C++ and VB are all interface languages.  What's your back end?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Oracle?

Comment: @JohnnyBones where did he mention the use of a database?

Comment: @rabbitguy - Can you have a data type in a front end only?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I mean, if you say `BigInteger something = new BigInteger(byte[] someArr);` that's not in a database, is it?

Comment: The answer to the question is obviously "yes". That doesn't mean it will be efficient though. Most of the built-in ones like Java `BigInteger` use quadratic run-time algorithms. So don't expect to get anything big. Libraries like GMP do have the right algorithms are limited to in-memory operations. If you combine that with swap space, then yes, it can be done without hand-rolling your own library. But it will be very slow.

Comment: What do you plan to do with irrational numbers that have no finite representation?

Answer (score -1):

Java's BigInteger class I believe is limited only by your computer's processing power

Comment: `BigInteger` isn't what he wants, since it has no fractional part.